# Coroutine not working, NullReferenceException Unity

Tags: unity, c#

When I run my game and collide with my object, I get a NullreferenceException error. I went through many posts I could find on Stackexchange and other websites, but nothing helped. When I did a Debug.Log, the Coroutine is triggered in both cases. I also checked my tags.

**Coroutine:**

```
public class Dialogue : MonoBehaviour {
public TextMeshProUGUI textDisplay;
public string[] sentences;
private int index;
public float typingSpeed;

public GameObject continueButton;

void Update() {
    if (textDisplay.text == sentences[index])
    {
        continueButton.SetActive(true);
    }
}

public IEnumerator Type() {
    foreach (char letter in sentences[index].ToCharArray())
    {
        textDisplay.text += letter;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
    }
}

public void NextSentence() {
    continueButton.SetActive(false);

    if (index < sentences.Length - 1)
    {
        index++;
        textDisplay.text = "";
        StartCoroutine(Type());
    } else {
        textDisplay.text = "";
        continueButton.SetActive(false);
            }
    }
}
```

**Coroutine call:**

```
public class Mace : MonoBehaviour {
private Dialogue dialogue;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D otherCollider) {
    if (otherCollider.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        StartCoroutine(dialogue.Type());
    }
  }
}
```

I did not cut my coroutine down more, as I think that all parts are at least somewhat relevant informations to my question.

Comment: Please tell us which line generates the exception.

Comment: Sorry, The 'StartCoroutine(dialogue.Type());' Line

Comment: @Vaillancourt And no, I looked through the article, it does not have an answer...

Comment: We close all questions about null pointer exception as duplicates to that question. And we try to help you via the comments ;)

Comment: From the code you posted, `dialogue` does not seem to be initialized. Is that the one that is null?

Comment: Didn't I initialize it with `private Dialogue dialogue;`?

Comment: I think this is only _declaring_ (a reference to) your object. You need to initialize it either with an external reference, or by creating it: `private Dialogue dialogue = new Dialogue();`.

Comment: Thank you!! Got it now. Duplicate was well set after all ;)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: @Vaillancourt Unfortunately, I got another error: `You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword`. When I try to add AddComnponent, it says that AddComponent doesn't exist in current context.

Comment: Hmm, is Dialogue a component that you have added to the GameObject?

Comment: Yes. I have added it to my dialogue manager and entered my sentences that I want to say and typing speed as well as set my continue button.

Comment: I don't know how this all works in Unity (dialogues), but typically, if you have two components on the same GameObject, say `Mace` and `Dialogue`, to get the reference of the `Dialogue` component in the `Mace` component, you do it in the `Start` method of the `Mace` component script by doing something like `dialogue = gameObject.GetComponent<Dialogue>();`.

Comment: If you have added the dialogue to a manager, you'll want to fetch the reference to the dialogue in the `Start` function of your `Mace` component.

Comment: Do you also know how it works if I have the 2 components on different gameObjects? Also, if I add both scripts to my Mace GameObject, the piece you posted gives me the error `An object reference is required for the non-static field etc. (CS0120)`

Comment: I suppose [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) is one way. I guess there are other approaches, but I don't know them.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but I am not trying to get a gameObject, but my other script. (I have been trying to fix the error for about 3-5 hours now)

Comment: Yes, you find the GameObject which holds your script component, then you get the component from it? `dialogManagerObject = GameObject.Find("/DialogueManager"); dialogue = dialogManagerObject.GetComponent<Dialogue>();`.

Comment: I have not worked that much with Unity so this is all theory ;)

Comment: I don't necesserily need my other gameObject, so I have both scripts on one gameObject now, still doesn't work. (CS0120) from the solution you recommended: `dialogue = gameObject.GetComponent<Dialogue>();`

Comment: Looks like you have a case for a new question :) Please create a new question, describing what you have, and what you want to achieve! Others will be able to chip in!

Comment: Alright, I'll eat dinner first ;)

Comment: Sure, no worries, the Internet will wait, and bon appétit :)